# How I can Open and close any application in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to open/close any application with a button in C#. I am opening or closing programs like Word, Excell.
However, I can open another program (stellerium.exe) but I can't close it. Help, please.

//open program
private void button14_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Stellarium\Stellarium.exe");
}

//close program
private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
        foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("Stellarium.exe"))
        {
            process.Kill();
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you kill it through Task Manager? If not, do you have permission?

Comment: `but I can't close it` - Explain why you think this. Show what you observed, any error message or something?

Comment: Yes, I have. How Can I do it? @Llama

Comment: @MatJ I want to open and close a program called "Stellarium" on the desktop via winform. I can open the program, but I cannot close it. it doesn't give any error. the program remains open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it solved.

//close program

```
 private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcessesByName("stellarium"))
        {
            proc.Kill();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Get Process Id of the Process and use

Process.GetProcessById(Processid).Kill();

Answer (score 0):

```
var runningProcesses = Process.GetProcesses().ToList();

foreach(Process runningPrcocess in runningProcesses)
{
    if (runningPrcocess.ProcessName.ToLower().Equals("winword"))
    {
        runningPrcocess.Kill();
    }
}
```

You can change windowrd with your app process name an try it.

Comment: I tried and it didn't work.

//close program
        private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var runningProcesses = Process.GetProcesses().ToList();

            foreach (Process runningPrcocess in runningProcesses)
            {
                if (runningPrcocess.ProcessName.ToLower().Equals("Stellarium.exe"))
                {
                    runningPrcocess.Kill();
                }
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

The process name may be different to what it is in task manager (maybe)

Use this code to get the exact process

```cs
 Process[] process = Process.GetProcesses();
            foreach (Process proc in process)
            {
                //Find your process name properly this way
                Console.WriteLine($"\"{proc.ProcessName}\"");
            }
```

If that doesn't work try running the program as administrator

Comment: I tried. Doesn't work.